# Don't hurry. vs Take your time

Tags: sentence-meaning

I wonder if you could explain me these sentences might have the same meaning? Are they interchangeable?

> **Don't hurry.**

> **Take your time.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have fairly similar meanings, but I might use 'don't hurry' to mean 'Be sure to perform the task you are starting carefully without rushing and making mistakes', and 'take your time' to mean 'Don't worry about any time limit when performing this task'.